# Adding AngularJS page as a Joomla menu item

Tags: extension, joomla, permissions, angular

I created an AngularJS extension that has a page that needs to be viewable outside of CiviCRM's administration area.

To view it inside CiviCRM, the URL is:

`administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/a/#/productgallery/gallery`

Which displays my AngularJS page as so:

[image]

So my current attempt to get it forward facing on a Joomla site is to make a Menu Item of type "URL' like so:

[image]

However, by not being inside CiviCRM's administration panel, the permissions forbid it.

[image]

How can I get this page accessible via a menu item to anyone?

Comment: Are you trying to make it available in the admin end of Joomla or on the front end? To registered users or public? Have you checked on ACL/permissions?

Comment: @MtnPavlas Trying to make it public for anyone to see. As for your second question, I tried implementing the hook here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_permission/ I replaced the string "CiviMonitor" from the example with my extension. It added the permission to the list of permissions and I marked it allow all, but it still doesn't work. I tried different cases for my extension too, `ProductGallery` , `Productgallery`. Not sure how to implement this hook correctly, or if it is even the right one.

Comment: Hey Kurt, this may not be the solution you're looking for, but honestly for any front-end list views of "things that are managed by Civi / stored in the Civi tables", we heavily rely on the AlterReports component by AlterBrains.com. I'm happy to share a few examples via a screenshare if that helps you. Between CiviCRM, AlterReports and Seblod, we're able to build full-fledged web apps for anything we can dream of.